# Replacing quotes in a Java String only on specific places

Tags: java, regex

We have a String as below.

```
\config\test\[name="sample"]\identifier["2"]\age["3"]
```

I need to remove the quotes surrounding the numbers. For example, the above string after replacement should look like below.

```
\config\test\[name="sample"]\identifier[2]\age[3]
```

Currently I'm trying with the regex as below

```
String.replaceAll("\"\\\\d\"", "");
```

This is replacing the numbers also. Please help to find out a regex for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please also pay attention to the big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area (when you're initially asking the question), entire toolbar full of formatting aids, **[?]** button giving formatting help, and post preview area. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267354/java-string-replaceall-with-back-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replaceAll with this regex `\"(\d+)\"` so you can replace the matching of `\"(\d+)\"` with the capturing group `(\d+)` :

```
String str = "\\config\\test\\[name=\"sample\"]\\identifier[\"2\"]\\age[\"3\"]";
str = str.replaceAll("\"(\\d+)\"", "$1");
//----------------------^____^------^^
```

Output

```
\config\test\[name="sample"]\identifier[2]\age[3]
```

## regex demo

---

Take a look about [Capturing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Comment: How does it work? Code dumps are not useful answers.

Comment: what did you mean @T.J.Crowder i think i use a basic regex no?

Comment: Well, the OP wasn't able to come up with it, so some explanation of what it does would make sense. Teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: thank you @T.J.Crowder what about the new version i agree the first version was not clear

Comment: Thanks YCF_L. It worked with the regex mentioned. I was missing to use "$1" in the replacement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We can try doing a blanket replacement of the following pattern:

```
\["(\d+)"\]
```

And replacing it with this:

```
\[$1\]
```

Note that we specifically target quoted numbers only appearing in square brackets.  This minimizes the risk of accidentally doing an unintended replacement.

**Code:**

```
String input = "\\config\\test\\[name=\"sample\"]\\identifier[\"2\"]\\age[\"3\"]";
input = input.replaceAll("\\[\"(\\d+)\"\\]", "[$1]");
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
\config\test\[name="sample"]\identifier[2]\age[3]
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks Tim for the detailed explanation. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(?:"(?=\d)|(?<=\d)")
```

and replace it with nothing == ( `""` )

fast test:

```
echo '\config\test\[name="sample"]\identifier["2"]\age["3"]' | perl -lpe 's/(?:"(?=\d)|(?<=\d)")//g'
```

the output:

```
\config\test\[name="sample"]\identifier[2]\age[3]
```

test2:

```
echo 'identifier["123"]\age["456"]' | perl -lpe 's/(?:"(?=\d)|(?<=\d)")//g'
```

the output:

```
identifier[123]\age[456]
```

---

**NOTE**

if you have only a single double quote `"`  it works fine; otherwise you should add quantifier `+` for both beginning and end `"`

test3:

```
echo '"""""1234234"""""' | perl -lpe 's/(?:"+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)"+)//g'
```

the output:

```
1234234
```