# replacing regex pattern in java similar to notepad++

Tags: java, regex

I can replace
(.*)  with \1 in notepad++
for e.g. string

**aaa hello how are u bbb**

if i do below in notepad ++ it works

```
find : aaa(.*)bbb
replace: ccc \1

output: ccc hello how are u
```

How to do similar in JAVA , i can match pattern using str.matches but how to replace it as above

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267354/java-string-replaceall-with-back-reference/36268323

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java String.replaceAll() with back reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267354/java-string-replaceall-with-back-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, using `replaceAll` and `$1` for first group

```
text.replaceAll("aaa(.*)bbb", "$1"); 
// or
text.replaceAll("^aaa(.*)bbb$", "$1");  // match whole input string below
```

`replaceAll` searches all matches of first argument as regular expression and replaces it with second argument. Dollar in second argument are used to captures sequences (groups). To just replace once<sup>**1**</sup>, use `replaceFirst()`.

Similar can be done with a `Matcher`:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("aaa(.*)bbb").matcher(text);
matcher.replaceAll("$1");
```

---

Note **1**: since using `(.*)`, the pattern will be found at most once - `.*` tries to match as much as possible. Example: if `text = "aaa first bbb and aaa second bbb"` the group in `aaa(.*)bbb` will match `" first bbb and aaa second "` - the largest sub-sequence between `aaa` and `bbb`. This can be *prevented* using `(.*?)` (reluctant quantifier) that tries to match the smallest sub-sequence possible.